# Solr - return only men's shoes when we have both men's and women's shoes in same category

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search

I am using Solr for implementing search on ecommerce site and it works great.

I have shoes for both women's & men's shoes under same category shoes with facet for women & men and the product name has women or men defined in product names.

When I search for 'men's shoes', it also give me women's shoes and they are ranked higher then men's shoes.

How can I have only men's shoes returned in this case?

Comment: Could you post the query, that you’re running agains Solr?

Comment: its a edismax search query on product name, short description, full description and specifications (filters)

Comment: Please paste you full query.